# Can't connect to SVN with tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

I have a server with SVN installed

Lately, I installed a new router in the office (D-Link) and ever since then - I can't connect to the SVN remotely using tortoise SVN (connecting the server directly to the internet solves the issue)

The weird thing is that when the server is connected through the router I can access the repository through the browser (e.g. `http://myip:8081/svn/project`), but still can't connect through the tortoise repo-browser (the following error message appears: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection).

Of course I added port-forwarding from 8081 to the SVN server, but no luck.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confirmed you could access to the SVN server as `http://myip:8081/svn/project`;  can you also confirm your local repo has the same URL?  This is because you wrote you used port-forwarding, which implies that the SVN URL in your existing local repo might be different from the "current" SVN URL `http://myip:8081/svn/project`.

If that doesn't help, you can try resetting credentials:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153489/how-to-change-users-in-tortoisesvn

Lastly, you can install the Wireshark port sniffer to look into the traffic.

- http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my ISP blocked the access to some 'suspicious' protocols (one of the was webdav). don't know why they thought I need that kind of protection and why they didn't let me know it's there... anyway, now everything's back to normal